# Selecting data from 2 tables with PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am relatively new to PHP and SQL and I am creating a simple blog tool for my own page and I'm stuck on how I can make a comment section.
I have 2 tables
general, which contains the blog post and additional information
comments, which contains comments

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "blog";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die ("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE hidden = 'false' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo "<div class='blogpost'>
          <div class='blogbody'></div>";

     //I need to do a query into the comments table at this point to find
     //all comments matching the criteria to be matched with the post here.
     echo "<div class='comments'></div></div>";
   }
}
else{
    echo "no posts";
}
```

I manage to get the blogposts working but as soon as I try a second query by adding

```
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn2->connect_error){
    die ("connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
}
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE $row["parent"] ORDER BY id DESC";
$result2 = $conn2->query($sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){

    }
}
else{
    echo "no comments";
}
```

it all just breaks. I am not able to throw in a loop that gets all the comments for the specific post before it starts loading additional posts.

How would I go on about solving this? I might need a little spoonfeeding with comments in any code samples,

Comment: that's where it breaks: `WHERE $row["parent"] ORDER`. Change that to `WHERE parent={$row['parent']} ORDER`. I now assumed the column name `parent` - change that to the actual one. [it's the quotes that give you a syntax error]

Comment: but to make it simpler read about `join`s

Comment: and __allways__ check for errors. in php and in db (mysqli_error)

Comment: Using prepared statements for ***all*** of your queries will save you tons of headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the second query to fixed the problem.

```
WHERE $row["parent"] ORDER. Change that to WHERE parent={$row['parent']} ORDER
```

Thanks to Jeff for providing this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the primary key of the post and that can be used in comments table as a foreign key so that you can easily make your query with that will show all the comments against that specific post. Then the query will be like this:

```
 $postid=$row['post_id'];
```

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$postid' ORDER BY post_id DESC";